# Handler: "onTap" Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer Error Flutter

Tags: flutter

i am using GestureDetector and onTap()  in flutter i have

an error:

`(Handler: "onTap" Recognizer:  TapGestureRecognizer")` when clicking the `onTap()` Event

I cannot show the next Screen

I Used route method:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('AboutUsScreen');
```

and MaterialPageRoute method this `

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutUsScreen()));`
```

```
Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  //shrinkWrap: bool.fromEnvironment("true"),

                  children: <Widget>[
              

GestureDetector(
                      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                      onTap: () {
                        // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('AboutUsScreen1111111');

                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                             builder: (context) => AboutUsScreen()));
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/about');

                         Navigator.push(
                             context,
                             MaterialPageRoute(
                                 builder: (context) =>
                                     new AboutUsScreen1111111()));

                       
                      },

                        child: const Card(
                          elevation: 10,
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.document_scanner,
                                    fill: BorderSide.strokeAlignCenter),
                                Text(
                                  "AboutUS",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 28,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
            
                  ],
                ),
              )
```

What is the problem?

Comment: why are you doing Navigator.push twice in your onTap?

Comment: This is just an example of my code and some stuff
 Which have I tried?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run this, it works:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        //shrinkWrap: bool.fromEnvironment("true"),

        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const  AboutUsScreen()));
            },
            child: const Card(
              elevation: 10,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.document_scanner,
                        fill: BorderSide.strokeAlignCenter),
                    Text(
                      "AboutUS",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 28,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

kindly let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Your Code is Run .Thank You

Comment: The solution was strange
I have separated the body of my widget out of main widget types widget statelesswidget and run it.it is very strange .

The Error Can About  BuildContext But I Can't know if it has Any RelationShip.
thank You very match

Comment: @Ameer can you kindly vote my answer

Answer (score 0):

The solution was strange
I have separated the body of my widget out of main widget (type of widget statelesswidget) and run it.
it is very strange .

The Error Was About BuildContext But I Can't know if it has Any RelationShip.
thank for all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).